# How to add featured location to the top of the near list?

Tags: foursquare

Foursquare api: How to add featured location to the top of the near results list?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to understand your question so correct me if I'm wrong. But these are your two options:

You want to add a featured venue that you yourself define to a list of venues retrieved from the API. In which case you would have to do manually that has nothing to do with the API.

or you want a list of featured venues as defined by foursquare which would be the explore endpoint:
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore